# Visual Studio 2013 dll export linkage error (LNK2019/LNK1120)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

I know similar question has been asked before, but it looks like there is something different in what concerns classes export than a simple function ... I have checked all those solutions, checked all the suggestions but it still looks like I am missing something ...

What's happening:

- I have a master C++ project written in Visual Studio 2013 and I want to add a dll library with various utils. I have created a dummy one, with basically no functionality, but it fails to compile:

```
    2>  TestSvc_i.c
    2>TestSvc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall CUtils::CUtils(void)" (__imp_??0CUtils@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
    2>C:\Work\TestSvc_root\Debug\TestSvc.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And the code in the main project looks like this:

```
extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    CUtils *a = new CUtils();
    delete a;

    return 1;
}
```

I have the following setup:

- the master project written in C++ with Visual Studio 2013;
- I am using Unicode charset and the runtime is used in a shared dll;
- `_UNICODE` is defined;
- SubSystem: Windows (`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`);
- I want to create an utility library that should be used in a shared dll. The code looks like this:

Utils.h:

```
#ifdef UTILS_EXPORTS
#define UTILS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define UTILS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the Utils.dll
class UTILS_API CUtils {
public:
    CUtils(void);
};
```

Utils.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utils.h"

// This is the constructor of a class that has been exported.
// see Utils.h for the class definition
CUtils::CUtils()
{
    return;
}
```

- I checked the dll-project settings and basically, they're all as in main project;
- `UTILS_EXPORTS` is defined in dll-project so normally, all definitions should have `__declspec(dllexport)` (as expected, not defined in `UTILS_EXPORTS`);
- I have the following preprocessor definitions: `WIN32`;`_DEBUG`;`_WINDOWS`;`_USRDLL`;`UTILS_EXPORTS`;
- dll-project is added as a dependency to master-project;
- the dll is copied under `$(SolutionDir)\Debug` but not under `$(SolutionDir)\$(MasterProject)\Debug` - I don't know why. I manually copied it, but I still have the same problem;
- I ran `DUMPBIN` utility on Utils.dll and here is how it looks:

```
    C:\Work\TestSvc_root\Debug>DUMPBIN /EXPORTS /SYMBOLS Utils.dll
    Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


    Dump of file Utils.dll

    File Type: DLL

      Section contains the following exports for Utils.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    53C632A8 time date stamp Wed Jul 16 10:07:04 2014
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011154 ??0CUtils@@QAE@XZ = @ILT+335(??0CUtils@@QAE@XZ)
          2    1 000110C8 ??4CUtils@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z = @ILT+195(??4CUtils@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)

    Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

- I have tried to "sniff" the value of UTILS_API:

```
    #define DO_QUOTE(X)        #X
    #define QUOTE(X)           DO_QUOTE(X)
    #define MY_QUOTED_VAR      QUOTE(MYVARIABLE)

    #pragma message(QUOTE(UTILS_API))
```

which dumps the correct value: when "used" from dll, it dumps `__declspec(dllexport)`, and when used from main-project it dumps `__declspec(dllimport)`

So, any hint? It looks like there is something that has to do with class export definition/method decoration ... In previous plain old Visual C++ there used to be a "def" file where you could map the exported names ... but in this new version, I am lost.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if, as an experiment, you manually add the .lib file to the list of linker inputs?

Comment: Is the Utils.dll compiled with VS 2013 as well?  Microsoft don't guarantee a compatible C++ ABI between major releases.

Comment: @Steve - yes, VS2013. They're all in the same solution and the project dependencies are set correctly (master depends on dll). I checked the compiler output and the order is correct.

Comment: Don't know for VS2013, but for VS2010, adding the DLL project as a dependency is NOT enough. Make sure your exe has "use library dependency Inputs" to "yes" in Linker properties.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka - it works if I manually add the lib to dependencies. But doesn't mean that it will use the library output and not the dll?

Comment: The .lib file is used to link with .dll.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka - would you please add your comments as an answer?

Comment: @manuell - I tried your suggestion and as much sense it makes, it failed to link ... anyway, it looks like manually adding the lib file for that dll it works. Thanks for your input/help!

Comment: Then, try "Link Library Dependencies" to "yes", instead of "use library dependency Inputs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you may explicitly add .lib file (generated during the build of your .dll) to the list of input libraries in the linker options of the main project.