# C++ .dll adding in Visual Studio - yet another "unresolved external symbol"

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am adding .dll to C++ project.
IDE: Visual Studio 2013

What I did:

- Added directory with headers to `VC++ Directories -> Include Directories`

. It's ok, I can include headers, IntellySense sees names
   in these files.

- Added .lib file to `Additional Dependencies` section and a path to this
  file in both `VC++ Directories -> Library Directories` and `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`.
- Placed actual .dll file to DEBUG folder (also to project folder, just
  to be sure)
- Used `dumpbin.exe` to get sure I have exported all needed classes in my
  .dll

And I still get a bunch of unresolved externals with functions stored in that .dll. Any suggestions?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776853/visual-studio-2013-dll-export-linkage-error-lnk2019-lnk1120?rq=1) and set `Use library Dependency Inputs` to Yes. Still no luck.

Some more info:
Error example:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: double __thiscall Fem::Node::GetX(void)" (__imp_?GetX@Node@Fem@@QAENXZ) referenced in...
```

This function in dumpbin output:

```
 172   AB 000F81A0 ?GetX@Node@Fem@@QEAANXZ
```

I see some difference in the last part of the name. Somehow, as I mentioned in the comments, I got it working in Qt project with Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: Odd that it finds your headers; the header directories should go into "Include Directories", not "Library Directories". Did you add the directory with the *.lib file(s) to "Library Directories"?

Comment: @Wintermute Sorry, failed to write a question properly. Sure, I have .h in include directories and .lib in Library Directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a bad idea, since it doesn't lead to a reusable library.  The application can't be rebuilt with a new compiler or even new compile settings without also rebuilding the DLL.  It is safer to just compile the classes you use in statically.  That said, there are some benefits if used in conjunction with delay-loading, so...

In order to store a class implementation in a DLL, while building the DLL you must use `__declspec(dllexport)` on the class, and when consuming it there must be `__declspec(dllimport)`.  Import libraries have shims to forward free function references to DLLs but those don't work for classes and class members.

Usually macros are used to accomplish the switch between `dllexport` and `dllimport`.

---

Now that you've shown mangled names, the difference becomes apparent, and demangling gives a clue to where the problem came from.

Linker is looking for

```
public: double __thiscall Fem::Node::GetX(void)
```

But DLL is exporting

```
public: double __cdecl Fem::Node::GetX(void) __ptr64
```

Notice that the calling conventions are different; if this had linked, you would have crashed as soon as you tried to call this function.

**You cannot use exports from a DLL that have C++ signatures from an application compiled differently.**  Are you mixing architectures (x86 vs x86_64 vs ARM)?  Can't do that either, not even using highly-compatible C calling signatures.

Comment: Yes, it was made to be a reusable library. I use
 `#if FEMCOREDLL_EXPORTS 
#define FEMCOREDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FEMCOREDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif` to export/import classes. Also, I got a QT project with the same .dll working fine. DLL was created in Visual Studio.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan: Your question is missing too many details.  Give an example of the linker errors, and an example of the corresponding lines of dumpbin output.  Probably you've violated the One Definition Rule via different compiler settings (structure packing and so on) and were lucky enough to have the compiler catch it via different name-mangling.  But even having the names match is no guarantee.  Doing this creates strong coupling between application and DLL -- you'll need to build both in exactly the same way.

Comment: Added some info to the question,

Comment: Yeah, that difference in the mangled names makes it clear that the problem has nothing to do with the directory settings you originally posted.  What do you get from undname, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2592972/103167)?

Comment: Yep, I just done the same thing with undname and saw this __ptr64. The problem was hidden in Visual Studio extension I installed before - it changed default platform to ARM, I guess. So, you helped me a lot, thank you!